# 'Destination not crawlable' error in Google Ads, other ads are working

Tags: google-ads-api, robots.txt

I've got a 'destination not crawlable' error on two ads in two different ad groups.

The URLs being used are identical to the other ads that are running fine.

So far the folks at Google haven't been much help, they're saying my robots.txt file is incorrect.

Currently it's here: https://easytrimreveals.com/robots.txt

One of our other websites has the same code (minus the sitemap) and the ads are running fine.

Is there any specific code I should be using in robots.txt to allow Google to crawl my site?

Comment: Try check this link for u issue  - https://support.google.com/google-ads/thread/7818856?hl=en

Comment: Thanks, we have no reference to bat.bing from what I can see..

Comment: I'm positive glaring JS errors could block crawls. Try fixing them. Also all your 3rd party tracking cookies/requests are annoying.

Comment: Working on those JS errors with the theme right now. Sorry I'm not the most robust web developer. Are you talking about the HubSpot tracking code? or the Google Analytics tracking? both?

Comment: It's pretty damn pathetic of Google to put the onus on the site developers/maintainers to figure out how Googles system works! Google should be able to say "not crawlable because X JS issue, X in robots.txt..." etc... they should not as in there response on the support formum WBLord linked say "also, not all ads are checked for all potential policy issues all the time -- a policy-flag may be triggered at any time, regardless of any past success." - so in otherwords they are saying it may work and then not work and then work again without you doing anything, that is truly an insane system!